# C++ Fail to Call Command Line Tool from Application + no permissions

Tags: c++, xilinx

I am attempting to build a C++ application which calls the command line tools that come with Xilinx ISE (sch2vhdl, xst, ngdbuild... etc) to automate a series of builds. The application encounters an error thrown by one of the tools (xst) only when called by the application so this makes me think that this is a permission issue with C++ rather than with anything from Xilinx.

The idea behind the C++ application is to use the System() function to interface with the command prompt exactly how I do it manually. I am capable of performing the synthesis from the windows command prompt with these same commands thus proving my method is possible. However, when I call the xst tool from the application the tool is successfully called and runs but fails with a 'no write access' error. The exact statement works perfectly when I copy and paste it into command line but using the System() function fails.

For those familiar with Xilinx I simply call these two commands:

```
sch2hdl -batch C:/Users/Nick/Documents/XilinxProjects/SingleItemTest/sch2HdlBatchFile
xst -ifn C:/Users/Nick/Documents/XilinxProjects/SingleItemTest/item.xst -ofn C:/Users/Nick/Documents/XilinxProjects/SingleItemTest/item.syr
```

Again, they are both successful when I call them from cmd. The second one, XST fails when the C++ application uses the exact same statement.

WHERE IT FAILS: The xst tool creates a a folder 'xst' with three subfolders. The subfolders are then populated with important files for the next command I need to call (haven't gotten there yet). When the application runs it calls xst with the command above and gets the following error:

```
ERROR:Xst:439 - No write access in xst/projnav.tmp
```

This is just a guess but maybe any program called by C++ is given limited write ability for security reasons. If that is the case is there any way to change that? Other than that I am out of ideas.

Below is the C++ code I am currently working with for clarification

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdio.h>      
#include <stdlib.h>     
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sddl.h>
#include <windows.h>

void convertSchematicToHDL() {
    printf("Executing sch2hdl\n");

    //Call first command line tool
    system("sch2hdl -batch C:/Users/Nick/Documents/XilinxProjects/SingleItemTest/sch2HdlBatchFile");
}
void callXST() {
    printf("\n\nExecuting Synthesis\n");

    //Create the necessary subfiles for xst to populate
    std::string outputFolder = "C:/Users/Nick/Documents/XilinxProjects/SingleItemTest/xst";
    CreateDirectoryA(outputFolder.c_str(), NULL);
    outputFolder = "C:/Users/Nick/Documents/XilinxProjects/SingleItemTest/xst/projnav.tmp";
    CreateDirectoryA(outputFolder.c_str(), NULL);

    //===========================================================//
    //This is the line that fails
    system("xst -ifn C:/Users/Nick/Documents/XilinxProjects/SingleItemTest/item.xst -ofn C:/Users/Nick/Documents/XilinxProjects/SingleItemTest/item.syr");
}

//Create configuration files needed by xst
void makeInitFiles() {
    std::ofstream prjFile;
    prjFile.open("C:/Users/Nick/Documents/XilinxProjects/SingleItemTest/item.prj");
    prjFile << "vhdl work \"item.vhf\"";
    prjFile.close();
    std::ofstream syrFile;
    syrFile.open("C:/Users/Nick/Documents/XilinxProjects/SingleItemTest/item.syr");
    syrFile.close();
    std::ofstream xstFile;
    xstFile.open("C:/Users/Nick/Documents/XilinxProjects/SingleItemTest/item.xst");
    xstFile << "set -tmpdir \"xst/projnav.tmp\"\n";
    xstFile << "set -xsthdpdir \"xst\"\n";
    xstFile << "run\n";
    xstFile << "-ifn item.prj\n";
    xstFile << "-ifmt mixed\n";
    xstFile << "-ofn item\n";
    xstFile << "-ofmt NGC\n";
    xstFile << "-p xa3s100e-4-vqg100\n";
    xstFile << "-top item\n";
    xstFile << "-opt_mode Speed\n";
    xstFile << "-opt_level 1\n";
    xstFile << "-iuc NO\n";
    xstFile << "-keep_hierarchy No\n";
    xstFile << "-netlist_hierarchy As_Optimized\n";
    xstFile << "-rtlview Yes\n";
    xstFile << "-glob_opt AllClockNets\n";
    xstFile << "-read_cores YES\n";
    xstFile << "-write_timing_constraints NO\n";
    xstFile << "-cross_clock_analysis NO\n";
    xstFile << "-hierarchy_separator /\n";
    xstFile << "-bus_delimiter <>\n";
    xstFile << "-case Maintain\n";
    xstFile << "-slice_utilization_ratio 100\n";
    xstFile << "-bram_utilization_ratio 100\n";
    xstFile << "-verilog2001 YES\n";
    xstFile << "-fsm_extract YES -fsm_encoding Auto\n";
    xstFile << "-safe_implementation No\n";
    xstFile << "-fsm_style LUT\n";
    xstFile << "-ram_extract Yes\n";
    xstFile << "-ram_style Auto\n";
    xstFile << "-rom_extract Yes\n";
    xstFile << "-mux_style Auto\n";
    xstFile << "-decoder_extract YES\n";
    xstFile << "-priority_extract Yes\n";
    xstFile << "-shreg_extract YES\n";
    xstFile << "-shift_extract YES\n";
    xstFile << "-xor_collapse YES\n";
    xstFile << "-rom_style Auto\n";
    xstFile << "-auto_bram_packing NO\n";
    xstFile << "-mux_extract Yes\n";
    xstFile << "-resource_sharing YES\n";
    xstFile << "-async_to_sync NO\n";
    xstFile << "-mult_style Auto\n";
    xstFile << "-iobuf YES\n";
    xstFile << "-max_fanout 100000\n";
    xstFile << "-bufg 24\n";
    xstFile << "-register_duplication YES\n";
    xstFile << "-register_balancing No\n";
    xstFile << "-slice_packing YES\n";
    xstFile << "-optimize_primitives NO\n";
    xstFile << "-use_clock_enable Yes\n";
    xstFile << "-use_sync_set Yes\n";
    xstFile << "-use_sync_reset Yes\n";
    xstFile << "-iob Auto\n";
    xstFile << "-equivalent_register_removal YES\n";
    xstFile << "-slice_utilization_ratio_maxmargin 5\n";
    xstFile.close();
}

//Cleanup
void deleteFiles() {
    std::remove("C:/Users/Nick/Documents/XilinxProjects/SingleItemTest/item.prj");
    std::remove("C:/Users/Nick/Documents/XilinxProjects/SingleItemTest/item.syr");
    std::remove("C:/Users/Nick/Documents/XilinxProjects/SingleItemTest/item.xst");
}
int main()
{
    printf("Checking if processor is available...");
    if (system(NULL)) puts("Ok");
    else exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    deleteFiles();
    makeInitFiles();
    convertSchematicToHDL();
    callXST();
    return 0;
}
```

The output of the XST function when called by the C++ application

```
Release 14.7 - xst P.20131013 (nt)
Copyright (c) 1995-2013 Xilinx, Inc.  All rights reserved.
--> Parameter TMPDIR set to xst/projnav.tmp


Total REAL time to Xst completion: 0.00 secs
Total CPU time to Xst completion: 0.08 secs

--> Parameter xsthdpdir set to xst


Total REAL time to Xst completion: 0.00 secs
Total CPU time to Xst completion: 0.09 secs

--> 
TABLE OF CONTENTS
  1) Synthesis Options Summary
  2) HDL Compilation
  3) Design Hierarchy Analysis
  4) HDL Analysis
  5) HDL Synthesis
     5.1) HDL Synthesis Report
  6) Advanced HDL Synthesis
     6.1) Advanced HDL Synthesis Report
  7) Low Level Synthesis
  8) Partition Report
  9) Final Report
    9.1) Device utilization summary
    9.2) Partition Resource Summary
    9.3) TIMING REPORT


=========================================================================
*                      Synthesis Options Summary                        *
=========================================================================
---- Source Parameters
Input File Name                    : "item.prj"
Input Format                       : mixed
Ignore Synthesis Constraint File   : NO

---- Target Parameters
Output File Name                   : "item"
Output Format                      : NGC
Target Device                      : xa3s100e-4-vqg100

---- Source Options
Top Module Name                    : item
Automatic FSM Extraction           : YES
FSM Encoding Algorithm             : Auto
Safe Implementation                : No
FSM Style                          : LUT
RAM Extraction                     : Yes
RAM Style                          : Auto
ROM Extraction                     : Yes
Mux Style                          : Auto
Decoder Extraction                 : YES
Priority Encoder Extraction        : Yes
Shift Register Extraction          : YES
Logical Shifter Extraction         : YES
XOR Collapsing                     : YES
ROM Style                          : Auto
Mux Extraction                     : Yes
Resource Sharing                   : YES
Asynchronous To Synchronous        : NO
Multiplier Style                   : Auto
Automatic Register Balancing       : No

---- Target Options
Add IO Buffers                     : YES
Global Maximum Fanout              : 100000
Add Generic Clock Buffer(BUFG)     : 24
Register Duplication               : YES
Slice Packing                      : YES
Optimize Instantiated Primitives   : NO
Use Clock Enable                   : Yes
Use Synchronous Set                : Yes
Use Synchronous Reset              : Yes
Pack IO Registers into IOBs        : Auto
Equivalent register Removal        : YES

---- General Options
Optimization Goal                  : Speed
Optimization Effort                : 1
Keep Hierarchy                     : No
Netlist Hierarchy                  : As_Optimized
RTL Output                         : Yes
Global Optimization                : AllClockNets
Read Cores                         : YES
Write Timing Constraints           : NO
Cross Clock Analysis               : NO
Hierarchy Separator                : /
Bus Delimiter                      : <>
Case Specifier                     : Maintain
Slice Utilization Ratio            : 100
BRAM Utilization Ratio             : 100
Verilog 2001                       : YES
Auto BRAM Packing                  : NO
Slice Utilization Ratio Delta      : 5

=========================================================================

ERROR:Xst:439 - No write access in xst/projnav.tmp\


Total REAL time to Xst completion: 0.00 secs
Total CPU time to Xst completion: 0.40 secs

--> 

Total memory usage is 239576 kilobytes

Number of errors   :    1 (   0 filtered)
Number of warnings :    0 (   0 filtered)
Number of infos    :    0 (   0 filtered)
```

Comment: "any program called by C++ is given limited write ability for security reasons" - no.

Comment: There is no such thing as "permission issue with C++".

Comment: Make sure the current working dir for manual execution of the command and the call from within c++ are the same.

Comment: Maybe something is written to the current directory, so check that the working directory is the same. Also the environment variables could be different, but as you are on Windows this is less likely. As your files are in your Documents folder, make sure that you are running your program with the correct user account ("Nick"). Another reason could be UAC, maybe running your program in compatibility mode could help.